# How can I visit a friend's island in Dragonvale?

Tags: dragonvale

My kids have exchanged friend codes, and received gem bonuses.
How can they visit each other's islands?

Note:
Under social, there's a "Friends" pane that always reads "3 gifts available", but has no other entries other than "visit random island".  The "gifts" tab is similarly blank.  This is on a Kindle Fire HDX, with no Facebook accounts.

Answer (score 1):

To give gems to friends, and to visit friends worlds in Dragonvale, the player must connect the game to Facebook, and must be Facebook friends with the people they want to give gems or visit their friends parks.

The "visit random park" button will randomly pick a park the player can already visit. If the player has no parks to visit normally, then the "visit random park" will fail.

Comment: "Visit random park" always worked for me, despite having no park to manually visit...

Comment: @JohntheGreen, what device are you on? Neither my friends nor myself were able to randomly visit parks until we linked up our parks so there was somewhere to go.

Comment: I play on a Droid Razr.

Comment: W/o facebook on Kindle fire, I can visit a random park, but not a friend's park.